# Django model managers.py and models.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

given the following situation:
**models.py**

```
from .managers import PersonManager
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

**managers.py**

```
from .models import Person
from django.db import managers

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, person_dict):
        new_person = Person(
            first_name=person_dict['first_name']
            last_name=person_dict['last_name'])
        new_person.save()
```

How can I write my model manager to avoid circular import?
It is actually not working, my guess is that I would have to create my object inside my manager without refering to it as class Person, instead I should use a more general generic Django name. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few options here.

Firstly, you could define the model and the manager in the same file; Python has no requirement or expectation that each class is in its own file.

Secondly, you don't actually need to import the model into the manager. Managers belong to models, not the other way round; from within the manager, you can refer to the model class via `self.model`.

And finally, if that's all your manager is doing, there is no reason for it at all. Managers already have a `create` method; it takes keyword parameters, rather than a dict, but that just means you can call it with `Person.objects.create(**person_dict)`.

Comment: Hi, I have a lot of managers interacting with other models. I wanted to put my managers into a separate file. But I end up in a circular import problem. I guess I'll keep them in the same file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to import a different model (not the queryset's model) from the same file, **you can put the import statement inside the method where it's needed**. This will prevent the circular import.