# How do I import an object into its own manager?

Tags: python, django

I realize that my logic is flawed and its causing a circular import.

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

**managers.py** (kept separate from models.py)

```
class TicketManager(models.Manager):
    def create_in_atom(self, ticket):
        if type(ticket) is not Ticket:
            raise Exception('Not a Ticket object.')
```

This produces this error:

> NameError: global name 'Ticket' is not defined

And so then I tried to import it:

```
from models import Ticket
```

Which produces:

> ImportError: cannot import name Ticket

---

How do I check to see if an argument passed to a function of the TicketManager is of the type "Ticket", which the TickerManager falls under?

Comment: what about from .models import Ticket?

Comment: @Exprator ImportError: cannot import name Ticket

Comment: do you have model name TIcket? and is the models.py and manager.py in the same directory?

Comment: @Exprator Solved!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of import, you can dynamically get the model:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class TicketManager(models.Manager):
    def create_in_atom(self, ticket):
        if type(ticket) is not AppConfig.get_model('Ticket'):
            raise Exception('Not a Ticket object.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TicketManager(models.Manager):
def create_in_atom(self, ticket):
    if type(ticket) is not self.model:
        raise Exception('Not a Ticket object.')
```

The answer is "self.model".

Because you are importing managers.py into models.py, you already have access to the model.

[Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497181/django-model-managers-py-and-models-py)

Comment: It's the correct solution for your case probably, but has nothing to do with imports. Also, if I put TicketManager() on model Concert, and provide a Ticket instance, the exception will be raised because ticket is not of type Concert.